# PL/SQL compilation syntax error for trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have been trying to find the solution to my error in my sql query for a while and can't seem to find the cause/don't understand the error.

I'm trying to create a trigger that updates the primary key of a table if one of the main values gets updates (sexe and anneenais(anneenais is year of birth in french))

Here is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ChevauxUpdateId
BEFORE UPDATE OF anneenais, sexe ON chevaux
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.idcheval := TO_CHAR(:NEW.anneenais | :NEW.sexe | SUBSTR(:OLD.idcheval, 6, 5));

    UPDATE proprietede
        SET idcheval = :NEW.idcheval
            WHERE idcheval = :OLD.idcheval;
    
    UPDATE resultats
        SET idcheval = :NEW.idcheval
            WHERE idcheval = :OLD.idcheval;
END;
```

It gives me the error:

> 2/86      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of
> the following:     . ( * % & | - + / at mod remainder rem => ..    <an
> exponent (**)> || multiset
>
> 11/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when
> expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable
> persistable order    overriding static member constructor map

it gives me the error at this line:

```
:NEW.idcheval := TO_CHAR(:NEW.anneenais | :NEW.sexe | SUBSTR(:OLD.idcheval, 6, 5));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because concatenation operator is two consecutive pipe signs `||`, not just one `|`.

```
:NEW.idcheval := TO_CHAR(:NEW.anneenais || :NEW.sexe || SUBSTR(:OLD.idcheval, 6, 5));
```

---

You could have used `concat` function, but it gets *ugly* if there are more than two strings you're concatenating because it (`concat`) accepts only two parameters. Then you have to nest them and - as I said - it gets ugly.

Comment: man I feel so dumb, thank you so much!